# How to convert this raw query to knex native?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I currently have a manually composed query in knex.js that uses `knex.raw`:

```
db.raw(`SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES ${Array(ids.length).fill('(?)').join(',')}) v (__whereId)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = v.__whereId ORDER BY ?? ASC LIMIT 2) t
ON true`,
[...ids, table, `${table}.${field}`, primaryKey])
```

I'd like to convert it to use as much knex.js built-in stuff as possible, but every time I try to come up with cleaner options using `knex.wrap`, `knex.as` etc. I run in to something that is unconvertible, or I just don't know how to write it.

I know knex.js does not support `VALUES` in anything except insert, so that has to be something raw, but the other things probably should be possible

Comment: Hey! Can you provide raw SQL query (without `knex`)? Or just a hint what you are trying to do with it (it looks a bit messy in question).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?)) v (__whereId)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.id = v.__whereId ORDER BY foo.id ASC LIMIT 2) t
ON true`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my own question:

```js
    const values = db.raw(`(VALUES ${Array(ids.length).fill('(?)').join(',')}) AS v (__whereId)`, ids);
    const sub = db.table(table).whereRaw('??.?? = v.__whereId', [table, field]).orderBy(primaryKey, 'asc').limit(2).as('t');
    const query = db.from(values).joinRaw('left join lateral ? on true', sub).select();
```

The last part is the interesting part - apparently using `?` inside a raw input, and giving a sub query as the parameter for the placeholder triggers some internal knex logic to automatically wrap the query and the nested placeholders correctly.